# Flutter & Hive: Hive boxes are cleared, but then data is restored on restart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am having an issue with Hive in my Flutter app.

I am using the Hive DB to store data during data capturing - to prevent loss of data if the app is closed/device dies/etc.

Once the capturing is complete, the Hive DB data is cleared, as it is now stored in a cloud DB.

I am having an issue recently where the Hive boxes are shown to be cleared while debugging. However, when I restart the app, the data is still present and loaded into the Hive box.

This is a recent issue, and has only started occurring in the last few weeks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was being caused by some incorrect code that I had overlooked.

I was erroneously clearing and re-writing to the Hive Box without realising it - causing the box to be empty when debugging and in operation, but then containing the correct data on restart.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding any changes you make are separate from he actual stored data in your Box. To make it perm you need to use box.put.

I'm new to Flutter Dart and Hive so apologies for the loose explanation. What im describing can be found on the HIVE documentation:

https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write?id=every-object-only-exists-once

Comment: That's correct. The changes need to be persisted, but luckily Hive makes that easy with their straight forward methods when adding data to boxes.